# c++ get macro name in macro

Tags: c++, macros

How to get the macro name inside a macro?
Say we have:

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

#define MACRO() \
cout << __MACRO_NAME__ << endl

int main () {
    MACRO();
    return 0;
}
```

Expected output:

```
MACRO
```

Comment: What's the motivation behind this?

Comment: Nothing, just came out, and want to know whether C++ can do this.

Comment: Why not just type `#define MACRO() cout << "MACRO" << endl`?

Comment: I know alternative ways, but I just want to know, can or cannot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did little bit of research and I don't think that is doable in c++.

But you could use this:

```
#define MACRO2(x) cout << #x << endl
#define MACRO MACRO2(MACRO)
```

In this you can use `MACRO2` to do the task of `MACRO` and you can also access name of `MACRO` as an argument `x`.

Comment: Well, that's a feasible way.

So that I can do:

`#define MACRO2(x, ...) cout << #x << endl; domore(__VA_ARGS__)`
`#define MACRO(...) MACRO2(MACRO)`

Comment: Yeah! But I'm still confused, where could you use this?

Comment: Just to show which macro was used when debugging, or indicate the macro name in using batch of macros, for example, in a test framework.

Comment: ellipsis in macro arguments is a gcc extension, not standard.